# Validate subject line of an email message

Tags: c#, .net, email

Some characters are invalid in an email subject and will result in failure, for example carriage return. I accept subject line as an input.

**Is there a definitive description of what makes a valid email Subject?** I've looked in the what I think is the correct RFC [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) and can't find any.

**Are there any .Net libraries that will validate/sanitise an email subject line?** Particularly is there anything in the core libraries or in [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)?

Comment: RFC 5322 is the one you need

Comment: I don't think there's any invalid characters - though you might need to quote some values. Not that any mail client I know of could handle end-lines in the subject, mind you. Some characters have a special meaning, of course (e.g. specifying encoding), but all of those are handled just fine in .NET's email classes and methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just make sure there are no newline or carriage returns. That is what `System.Net.Mail` does.

```
//This is from the MailBnfHelper class of the System.Net.Mime namespace.
internal static bool HasCROrLF(string data)
    {
      for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; ++index)
      {
        if (data[index] == '\r' || data[index] == '\n')
          return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: Yep, it appears it does https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/System/net/System/Net/mail/Message.cs.